# calling one python script as a module within another python script and both scripts should work independently from command line as well

Tags: python, module

I have two scripts a.py and b.py. Both work independently from command line by providing relevant args. Both scripts run on linux box. Both scripts have numerous methods and main method. How can I call a.py into b.py as a module ? should I just 'import a' at the top of b.py and then call the relevant methods inside the main method of b.py ? or is there a way to directly call the main method of a.py inside b.py ?

Note: I don't want to create multiple supporting files like setup.py or **init**.py if that is possible. thanks

Comment: YES: should I just 'import a' at the top of b.py and then call the relevant methods inside the main method of b.py

Comment: do you function which starts code in scripts? ie. `def main()` which runs in `if __name__ == "__main__":`? If you import other file then it will run it as main process and it will stop previous code. If you will have code in starting function then you can use `threading` or `multiprocessing` to run this function in separated thread so both may run at the same time.

Comment: @Marat: I read somewhere that if I import the script on top, it will execute the whole script. I think that won't happen, correct ? I can call the methods at appropriate location to execute them ?

Comment: @furas : I am not able to understand what you are trying to say. I need to run the called script at a particular location in my calling script, I can't run them in parallel. WIll it work, if I import script at top and call the non-main methods in the main method of the calling script?

Comment: I was thinking you need to run it in parallel. But you don't need to run in parallel then even better. You can `import` like any other module and execute function from this script. Eventually it may need to add folder with this script to `sys.path` before `import`.

Comment: Not sure if its the best way, but it worked for now. I imported the other script at the top (its in same directory on server). Then created a new method in the calling script and called all relevant methods to create a single package and then called this new method in the main method. It is working for me. I will close the question with that note. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the best way, but it worked for now. I imported the other script at the top (its in same directory on server). Then created a new method in the calling script and called all relevant methods to create a single package and then called this new method in the main method. It is working for me. I will close the question with that note. Thanks –